# ggplot2: why grid.arrange not working?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to plot two lines char in a same plot with `ggplot2`. I'm aware that you can do it with grid.arrange but I certainly missing something in my code.

Here are my data, where I want to plot both time and rate

```
motor;trace;time;rate
monetDBIE;1m;5448;183553
monetDBIE;2m;8734;228990
monetDBIE;5m;19468;256831
Jena;1m;8273;120875
Jena;2m;16916;118231
Jena;5m;44776;111666
PGSQLIE;1m;6859;145793
PGSQLIE;2m;13106;152601
PGSQLIE;5m;32793;152471
```

And here is my code

```
require("ggplot2")
require("gridExtra")

w <- read.csv(file="loading.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";")

# first plot
p <- ggplot(data=w, aes(x=trace, y=time, colour=motor, shape=motor))

p <- p + geom_point(size=4)

p <- p + geom_line(size=1,aes(group=motor))

p <- p + geom_text(aes(label=time), hjust=-0.2, vjust=1)

p <- p + ggtitle("Triplestores ")

p <- p + labs(x = "Traces", y = "Temps (ms)")

p <- p + theme_bw()

# second plot
p2 <- ggplot(data=w, aes(x=trace, y=rate, colour=motor, shape=motor))

p2 <- p2 + labs(x = "Traces", y = "débit de chargement (triplets/s)")

p2 <- p2 + geom_point(size=4)

p2 <- p2 + geom_line(size=1,aes(group=motor))

p2 <- p2 + geom_text(aes(label=rate), hjust=-0.2, vjust=1)

p2 <- p2 + theme_bw()

grid.arrange(p, p2, nrow=2, ncol=1)

ggsave(file="loading.pdf")
```

But unfortunatly I still get only one char p2 see the picture [image]

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `grid.arrange` in `pdf` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
pdf(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"))
grid.arrange(p1, p2)
dev.off()
shell.exec(tf)
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me. What are `p1`, `factor(cyl)`, `mtcars` ?

Comment: `p1 ` and `p2` are two arbitrary ggplot objects. What is the original problem - do you want two grid-arranged plots in a pdf? Maybe I didn't get you..

Answer (score 0):

a better solution in my opinion is to avoid `grid.arrange` altogether and simply use `arrangeGrob`, which allows you the flexibility of using the `ggsave` function.

```
big_plot <- arrangeGrob(p, p2, nrow=2, ncol=1)
print(big_plot)

ggsave(big_plot, ...)
```

Comment: note that the first argument of `ggsave` is the filename, not the plot.